# Why valueOf() returning true when we place false in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why this statement is returning true in nested objects

```js
var value = new Boolean(new Boolean(false)).valueOf();
console.log(value);
```

we are giving false at the time of object creation.

Comment: Hint: check `typeof (new Boolean(false))`.

Comment: ECMA 2015: [7.1.13 `ToObject ( argument )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject) -> [19.3.1 The Boolean Constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boolean-constructor) -> [19.3.1.1 `Boolean ( value )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boolean-constructor-boolean-value) -> [7.1.2 `ToBoolean ( argument)`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean)

Comment: @Andreas Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's just the "official" version of your answer. You're welcome to add the information to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As per [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description)**

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean
>   value, if necessary. If the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false,
>   NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial
>   value of false. If the DOM object document.all is passed as a
>   parameter, the new boolean object also has an initial value of false.
>   All other values, including any object or the string "false", create
>   an object with an initial value of true.
>
> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the
>   true and false values of the Boolean object.
>
> Any object of which the value is not undefined or null, **including a
>   Boolean object whose value is false evaluates to true** when passed to
>   a conditional statement. For example, the condition in the following
>   if statement evaluates to true:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
if (x) {
  // this code is executed
}
```

> This behaviour does not apply to Boolean primitives. For example, the
>   condition in the following if statement evaluates to false:

```
var x = false;
if (x) {
  // this code is not executed
}
```

> Do not use a Boolean object to convert a non-boolean value to a
>   boolean value. Instead, use Boolean as a function to perform this
>   task:

```
var x = Boolean(expression);     // preferred
var x = new Boolean(expression); // don't use
```

> If you specify any object, including a Boolean object whose value is
>   false, as the initial value of a Boolean object, the new Boolean
>   object has a value of true.

```
var myFalse = new Boolean(false);   // initial value of false
var g = Boolean(myFalse);       // initial value of true
var myString = new String('Hello'); // string object
var s = Boolean(myString);      // initial value of true
```

> Do not use a Boolean object in place of a Boolean primitive.

---

**As we have seen above description now we are going to your question.**

`new Boolean(false)` it returns an Object whose value is false.

Now when you call it with this object, objects are by default considered as truthy value and hence it returns `true` for `.valueOf()`. Similarly, if you call it with `"false"`, it will also return true as its a valid value.

Comment: Though we both have referred to same doc, you seemed to have copied entire description. You should rather put specific parts and link the doc instead. But this is just my POV

Comment: @Rajesh can you refer my bottom description about an answer if not then please review last 2 paragraphs of an answer.

Comment: Not being picky but *new Boolean(false) it returns always false*. If this is true, `new Boolean(new Boolean(false))` should be interpreted as `new Boolean(false)`. Its `{value: false}` hence it is evaluated as true. Though you are pointing to correct area, terminology is a bit off.

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for your review and opinion.

Comment: I have edited your answer. If you think my edit is unnecessary, please revert it. Also apologies if you were offended by me editing your answer without your consent.

Answer (score 7):

> Why this statement is returning true in nested objects

Because `new Boolean(false)` returns a **Boolean Object** which is not a **falsey value**.

It is evaluated as

> `new Boolean(new Boolean(false)).valueOf()`
>
> `new Boolean(<<Boolean Object false>>).valueOf()`
>
> `(<<Boolean Object true>>).valueOf()`
>
> `true`

**Edit**

Adding info **@Andreas comment** - how **spec supports the evaluation** of the expression.

ECMA 2015: [7.1.13 ToObject ( argument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject) -> [19.3.1 The Boolean Constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boolean-constructor) -> [19.3.1.1 Boolean ( value )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boolean-constructor-boolean-value) -> [7.1.2 ToBoolean ( argument)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean)

Comment: @Rajesh I am assuming that only just :)

Comment: I added an answer but that seems to be a partial one. Just re-iterating Docs. Is it ok if I add that in your answer or you can add yourself as well

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, just saw the same. I have added the spec links which Andreas shared in his comment already.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new Boolean()` a new `Object` is created. So when passing that to another `new Boolean()` constructor, the argument is actually `truthy`. Hence, the newly created Boolean is a `true` value

Answer (score 0):

> Any object of which the value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement. For example, the condition in the following if statement evaluates to true:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
if (x) {
    // this code is executed
}
```

According to this definition from javascript documentation, the value is not undefined, so it evaluates to true. And when the outer expression evaluates it's value is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = new Boolean(new Boolean(false)).valueOf();
```

Check this statements in parts. First of all, innermost

```
new Boolean(false)
```

this returns `{ false }` object, which is truth. Not `undefined`

So, the statement becomes

```
new Boolean(true).valueOf() => becomes true
```